# Map TreeMap item returns null when gets a int higher than 0?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

```
    Score.clear();
    for (Client player : getPlayers()) {
        Client c = (Client) player;
        Score.put(c.gameScore, c);
    }

    Client WINNER = Score.get(Score.size() - 1);
    if (WINNER != null) {
        System.out.println("it works.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("its a null");
    }
```

**What it supposed to do:**

Loop through all clients, and then add the client's score, object into the Map collection, (treemap).
And then find the client that has the most score.

TreeMap collection goes from lowest int, to highest int like this: (-5, 0, 6, 8, 110, 647).

I tried the current code, when the clients have 0 score (All of them), it works fine and outputs "it works.". but once I get 200 score into one of the clients, it says "its a null".

**Why is it ending up being a null?**

```
public static Map<Integer, Client> Score = new TreeMap<Integer, Client>();
```

Comment: What happens if two clients have the same score?

Comment: It will select the last one anyway, doesn't it store them like that (1, 5, 7, 99, 101, 101) ?

Comment: You can't have two equal keys in a map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
Score.get(Score.size() - 1)
```

will *not* get the last entry of the map, but the value for a key which value is `Score.size() - 1`, if any. It is therefore normal that it does not work.

Since you use a `TreeMap`, it means it is also a `SortedMap`. Therefore you can do:

```
// declare the map
final SortedMap<Integer, Client> scores = new TreeMap<>();

// fill the map

// get the last entry
scrores.get(scores.lastKey());
```

Note that you should preferably stick to Java conventions: variable names should begin with a lowercase letter.

Another alternative would be to use a `SortedSet` with a custom `Comparator`.

Comment: Shouldn't TreeMap<> have Integer, Client?

Comment: @JunatanmDegraded not with Java 7, no. With Java 6, yes

Comment: According to what Arshajii commented, that I can't have two equal keys, is it possible to remove the other client's score if it already exists?

Comment: It will be done automatically for you. If you try and put two clients with the same score, the latest put will always win.

Answer (score 0):

Read this carefully:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

What you need is `lastEntry()`

Answer (score 0):

the

```
Score.get(Score.size() - 1)
```

is your mistake.
TreeMap.get has *not* an index as parameter but the key object.